# Why is "if" not working?

Tags: perl

```
my $trefer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER}; 
my $gk1 = substr($trefer, -4);
my $gk2 = ".swf";
my $antigk = $gk1;

if ($gk1 = $gk2) { 
  $antigk = $trefer; 
} 
else 
{  
  $antigk = $link; 
}
```

so whats wrong with this code? if is not working for example referal is 
`site.com/2nujroj49lni`, it should show me the `$link` but instead it shows me the `$refer`

why ? i dont get it

as long as it is not .swf i should get link not the referal
i searched over the internet and it looks legit . no errors as far as i can see but still not working

Comment: so the idea should be next .. if last 4 characters from referal are not .swf show link if are swf show .. referal..

Comment: "If" is working fine. It's your understanding of Perl's operators which is broken. You're using an assignment operator (`=`) where you need a comparison operator (`eq`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if ($gk1 = $gk2)
```

will always be true.  It's an assignment, not a comparison.  If they were numbers, you'd want:

```
if ($gk1 == $gk2)
```

but they're strings, so in Perl you'll need:

```
if ($gk1 eq $gk2)
```

Comment: +1, but if the code in the question is the OP's real code, then I think it would be better to write `if ($trefer =~ m/\.swf$/)`, rather than comparing substrings for equality.

Comment: True, but my goal was to clear up the confusion about the code he'd written.

Comment: @PaulRoub:  being pedantic, "will always be true" isn't.  If `$gk2` resolves to false, an empty string or zero for example, then the  result of the assignment will be false.

Comment: True, true. In this case, of course, we know it's a non-empty string -- good point, though.